# SMS receiver only works when a certain activity has been opened

Tags: java, android, sms, gsm

I've created an app that uses a BroadcastReceiver class to receive SMS messages within the app to change and control different things within the app when a certain text message has been received. I recently added a new activity to the app, now the problem is that if the app receives an SMS message it will crash unless the new activity has been started. Can anyone think why this might be?
thanks

this is my logcat of the crash error:

```
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.becatech.gsmzonecontroller/com.becatech.gsmzonecontroller.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at com.becatech.gsmzonecontroller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 07-31 15:51:50.135: E/AndroidRuntime(779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the new activity? and what do you do once you receive message?

Comment: the new activity does the same sort of thing as the first activity but in a different way, the first activity sends out text messages one at a time and the second sends out many at once. When the app receives a message with a certain command it will change toggle buttons acordingly to the command it has receieved

Comment: Would it be possible to launch the second activity in the background when the app is started??

Comment: so just start the activity containing those toggle buttons and pass the received message via Intent

Comment: What is the log when your app crashed?

Comment: Logcat precisely says that, there is a NullPointerException at MainActivity.java: line 66.. Check what's null there

Comment: So what is the code in line 66?

Comment: would that be line 66 in my main activity or in my receiver class?

Comment: The line 66 of MainActivity.java, it says in logcat.

Comment: Line 66 is simply a reference to one of my toggle buttons:
`Global.mytbSF = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleBtnZoneF);`

Comment: if I comment out line 66, it will still crash here. And also why would opening a second activity after my first cause it to not crash here?

Comment: You need to add two lines before line 66, `System.out.println("Global is null:" + (Global == null));` and `System.out.println("Find view is null:" + (findViewById(R.id.toggleBtnZoneF) == null));`, then see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nullPointerException at line 66 in your main activity

Answer (score 0):

Do this in you receiver to start the activity and send message:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Your_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("msg", message_received);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your activity you can check for the message and make changes to the toggle button